# Conversion of unicode string to hex representation in Python

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, hex

I have a list of unicode string e.g.

```
list1 = [u'00 01 02 03']
```

and I want to convert it into following list

```
list2 = [0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03]
```

I have converted list1 to simple string values as follow

```
list3 = ['0x00', '0x01', '0x02', '0x03']
```

but I need list2 as result.

Any suggestion to produce **list2** from **list1** directly or from **list3**.

Thanks

Comment: What if the original list has more strings in it?

Comment: yes it can be the case. In that case separate lists (like **list2**) will be needed for each string in original list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's always a single string in the original list, a list comprehension will do it quite easily;

```
list2 = [int(x, 16) for x in list1[0].split()]
```

...or for multiple strings to int lists, the somewhat more verbose;

```
list_of_list2s = [[int(x, 16) for x in y.split()] for y in list1]
```

Comment: Asking to learn: is the representation requested in list2 possible in python? I tried to type in that, but it gets automatically "translated" into decimal values into the list (as also per your solution).

Comment: @sal You can't keep the values in a specific format/base unless you store them as strings. An integer (as the case is whether it's '1' or '0x01' does not have an associated format and the format needs to be chosen when converting it to a string for output.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Yes it works. But if I have `list1 = [u'00 01 02 ff']` then the ouput with this will be `list2 = [0, 1, 2, 255]`. However I want output as `list2 = [0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0xff]`

Comment: @user3159610 If you want it output that way, you can convert it when displaying it. An integer does not have a specific format (for example 0x01) unless you store it as a string (which you didn't want to do).